# Сортировка вставками + бинарный поиск, реально?

Tags: java

Имеется задание:

> Дана последовательность натуральных чисел от 1 до 10.
>
> Нужно упорядочить данную последовательность методом ***"Сортировка вставками"***
>
> **Дополнительно:** Место помещения очередного элемента в отсортированную часть производить с помощью ***двоичного поиска***.

Вот код для сортировки вставками:

```
public static void insertMethod(int[] mass){
    for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
        int element = mass[i];
        int backIndex = i - 1;

        for (; backIndex >= 0; backIndex--) {
            if (element < mass[backIndex]) {
                mass[backIndex + 1] = mass[backIndex];
                
            }
            else break;
        }
        mass[backIndex + 1] = element;

    }
}
```

Вот код двоичного поиска:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] mass, int firstElement, int lastElement, int searchElement){
    int middle = 0;
    //условие, когда прекращаем
    if(lastElement >= firstElement){
        middle = firstElement + (lastElement - firstElement) / 2;

        //если средний элемент равен searchElement, вернуть его индекс
        if(mass[middle] == searchElement) return middle;

        //если средний элемент больше searchElement, то вызываем метод опять, только уже с суженными границами
        if(mass[middle] > searchElement) binarySearch(mass, firstElement, middle - 1, searchElement);

        //иначе тоже вызываем сами себя, только уже со сдвигом границ вправо
        else binarySearch(mass, middle+1, lastElement, searchElement);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Вопрос:** Я не понимаю, как можно совместить данных два способа сортировки. Ведь способ сортировкой вставками и так уже сортирует часть массива, чтобы вставить туда число. Как это реализовать?

Comment: На мой субъективный взгляд, за такие задачи (именно в такой постановке) нужно преподавателям отрывать головы и долго бить линейкой по пальцам. Вам вместо второго вложенного цикла в сортировке нужно вызвать бинарный поиск по уже отсортированной части массива, затем "раздвинуть" массив в точке, которую вернёт бинарный поиск, и вставит туда элемент. Так вот, процедура "раздвигания" будет выполняться за `O(n)` шагов, поэтому сложность метода всё равно остаётся `O(n**2)`, и бинарный поиск всё равно здесь не даёт существенного ускорения, а только пудрит мозги.

Comment: Я тоже так думаю.
Получается, что методом "Сортировка вставками" будет отсортировано только array[0] иarray[1], потом уже метод двоичного поиска до конца массива будет переставлять символы. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю. Если убирать второй вложенный цикл for (; backIndex >= 0; backIndex--), то от метода сортировки вставкой ничего не останется

Comment: Внутри вложенного цикла у вас сразу два действия: поиск места под вставку и одновременно раздвигание массива. Так вот, поиск места не нужен, вам этот поиск выполнит бинарный поиск, и вернёт позицию, куда вставить элемент. Затем вам нужно только написать (в цикле) сдвиг элементов подобно тому, как уже написано.

Comment: Боюсь, что за вас этого делать никто бесплатно не будет :)

Comment: Это такой вопрос, который требует денежных вложений в методах сортировки?)

Comment: Нет, просто время специалистов не является бесплатным, когда речь идёт о чьих-то домашних заданиях и простейших задачах. С удовольствием отвечаю на интересные задачи, где человек действительно пытался разобраться сам, но не смог. Для остальных у меня в профиле есть ссылка для вопросов.